# Magento 2 - Place Order if payment is completed

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-gateway

I have a custom payment method. When the place order button is triggered, I want to process my payment gateway. After this, if payment is a success order should be placed successfully.

Here is a method-renderer file.

```
define(
    [
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default'
    ],
    function (Component) {
        'use strict';
        return Component.extend({
            defaults: {
                template: 'Iostpay_Iostpaymagento/payment/iostpay'
            },
            getMailingAddress: function () {
                return window.checkoutConfig.payment.checkmo.mailingAddress;
            },
            getInstructions: function () {
                return window.checkoutConfig.payment.checkmo.mailingAddress;
            },
            placeOrder: function () {
                alert('heya');
                var getresp = transfer();
                console.log("transfer-resp: "+getresp);
                var form = document.getElementById("co-payment-form");
                form.submit();
            }
        });
    }
);
```

This is my placeOrder Button HTML.

```
<button class="action primary checkoutplaceorder"
        data-bind="
            click: placeOrder,
            attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
            css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()},
            enable: (getCode() == isChecked())
            "
        type="submit" disabled>
    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
</button>
```

Basically this is how I wanna do.

1. Click on placeOrder:-
   On click of place order, a payment modal will pop up. Then the user will make the payment from the modal-popup.
2. After making payment the user gets the payment response.
3. Place the Order successfully and submit the form.

Does anyone know about this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, do you want to do this only with knockout? otherwise you can use place order `checkout_submit_before` event

Comment: Hi, I want to process the payment and 
`place order successfully only if my payment is success.` 
 this is my button here for placeOrder

`<button  class="action primary checkoutplaceorder"
      data-bind="
       click: placeOrder,
       attr: {title: $t('Place Order')},
       css: {disabled: !isPlaceOrderActionAllowed()},
       enable: (getCode() == isChecked())
       "
                        type="submit" >
                    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Place Order'"></span>
                </button>`

Can i trigger placeOrder event with JS?

Comment: According to  my view, there is no need to do this by knockout, you can do this via observer, create a place order event, and check if you receive your custom payment method then do your code.

Comment: But i am making payment on click of placeOrder.

Comment: please share more details about the issue if possible

Comment: @trusha I have edited my question and added few lines for more summary. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did u get the solution? please share.